# Flowlayout control in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

In silverlight 4 Beta there used to be a contol called flowlayout control.
Now i am not able to see that in the silverlight 4 rc. please let me know if anything needs to be installed to get that control.

Answer (score 3):

Never heard of that in Silverlight or WPF. FlowLayoutPanel was a Windows Forms control. What you can use is the WrapPanel from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/).

```
<toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="150">
    <Button Content="Hello!" />
    <Button Content="Hello!" />
    <Button Content="Hello!" />
    <Button Content="Hello!" />
    <Button Content="Hello!" />
    <Button Content="Hello!" />
    <Button Content="Hello!" />
    <Button Content="Hello!" />
</toolkit:WrapPanel>
```